# Use of \r \n in value passed to `RedisModule_ReplyWithSimpleString` redis

Tags: c++, c, redis, hiredis

I have a simple module that implements new type in redis storage. This type holds simple string.
User can save such string `set-myType key value`
User can get string `get-myType key`

I faced with problem that if value contains `\r` or `\n` in a value I can't reply to a user. It fails with `Bad simple string value`

I investigated code of redis_module API and found that this error refers to hiredis during such check

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (p[i] == '\r' || p[i] == '\n') {
            __redisReaderSetError(r,REDIS_ERR_PROTOCOL,
                     "Bad simple string value");
        return REDIS_ERR;
    }
}
```

Redis itself add such symbols to my reply during `ReplyWithSimpleString`

```
int RM_ReplyWithSimpleString(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, const char *msg) {
    client *c = moduleGetReplyClient(ctx);
    if (c == NULL) return REDISMODULE_OK;
    addReplyProto(c,"+",1);
    addReplyProto(c,msg,strlen(msg));
    addReplyProto(c,"\r\n",2);  // HERE
    return REDISMODULE_OK;
}
```

Common redis command `get key` handles such symbols just fine.

My question: is there any possibility to store value with `\n` or `\r` and successfully reply with it to user via `ReplyWithSimpleString` or any other API.

Comment: The redis protocol [explicitly forbids](https://redis.io/docs/reference/protocol-spec/#simple-strings) \r and \n in simple strings. You need [bulk strings](https://redis.io/docs/reference/protocol-spec/#bulk-strings) for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your value might contain '\r' and '\n', you should call `RedisModule_ReplyWithStringBuffer`. This method returns a Bulk String Reply instead of Simple String Reply, and it's binary safe.